# Add Core Data Attributes depending on a date

Tags: macos, core-data, attributes, entity

I've created a code with a simple table view linked to a core data entity, let's call this entity "book". in the table view are present few attributes of the book, like rating, title, author, all declared properly in the core data model.
now, i'd like to add a new feature: i want my program to let me select in which year i read this book, maybe even more then one; so i created a lot of check button labelled with all the years from 2005 to 2013 and I'd like to store this bool values in core data as well.
I can declare all the attributes straight in the core data model, but when the new year is coming, how can i add a new attribute? I want my program to add this attribute itself when the 2014 comes, is there any way to do that?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to solve this is to create a new entity `Read` that has a many-to-one relationship with `Book`. You can store start date, end date etc. in this entity, even a rating.

Your idea about year data, i.e. the actual year number being stored in attribute names is outlandish. Maybe you should consider taking some basic computer programming lessons.

Comment: I found the same solution studying a bit more on Core Data Relationships. I'll take in consideration your suggestion, but it's just an hobby for me at the moment. thanks again.